# JENKINS- aws configure --profile

Tags: jenkins, automation, devops, aws-cli

im trying to automate the creation of a new user with aws cli

```
            steps{
                    sh '''
                        aws --version
                        aws configure --profile superappaws
                    '''
                
            }
```

This throws me an EOF error.

```
+ aws configure --profile superappaws
AWS Access Key ID [None]: 
EOF when reading a line
```

is there a way to enter this credentials? or how can i create the user with jenkins?

i have to created a pipeline with this steps

activate env
pip install awscli
aws configure --profile superappaws
Enter the credentials
export AWS_PROFILE=superappaws
aws s3 ls >> check if the user is created

Answer (score 0):

You can set the AWS credentials as environment variables.

```
environment {
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('jenkins-aws-secret-key-id')
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('jenkins-aws-secret-access-key')
    }
```